# Springsource Tool Suite UML plugin

Tags: spring, eclipse-plugin, uml

Is there an open-source "UML Modeling" plugin for Spring source Tool Suite? I tried installing UML2 plugin provided for Eclipse but it doesn't seem to work.

After some googling, I found Object Aid which isn't licensed open source software!
Is there any other plugin available?

Regards
Surekha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UMLet](http://www.umlet.com/) works fine, but it can be used to make diagrams from scratch. It does not create class diagrams from java classes though!

Answer (score 1):

You can search on the Eclipse Marketplace like this:
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/apachesolr_search/uml?filters=ss_cck_field_status:Production/Stable%20ss_cck_field_licensetype:EPL

But except for Topcased only very small parts of UML are covered. Most likely you will not be satisfied with the non-commercial tools... with "Advanced Search" you can switch the license type to "Commercial" then ;)